# How to replace array with particular value and adding into the specific index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime

Following are code snippet::

```
  let dayOfWeek=["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
  let officeHoursList: [
{dayOfWeek: "Wednesday", beginHour: "08:30 AM", endHour: "04:30 PM"}]
```

Here I need to compare both of the array and if the dayOfWeek is not present into the officeHoursList then it will add remaining dayOfWeek into the officeHoursList.

For Example in this case the final output would be

```
officeHoursList: [
{dayOfWeek: "Monday", beginHour: "00:00 AM", endHour: "00:00 PM"},
{dayOfWeek: "Tuesday", beginHour: "00:00 AM", endHour: "00:00 PM"},
{dayOfWeek: "Wednesday", beginHour: "08:30 AM", endHour: "04:30 PM"},
.
.
.
{dayOfWeek: "Sunday", beginHour: "00:00 AM", endHour: "00:00 PM"}]
```

Here the value of array officeHoursList is dynamic in this case it is only contains the Wednesday but it would be any dynamic value from Monday to Sunday.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Thanks for your question, what have you tried on which you need help with?

Comment: So if nothing is passed you want a 12 hour default with values of `beginHour: "00:00 AM", endHour: "00:00 PM"`?  Please show the code that you have attempted so that we may help you fix it.

Comment: "Here I need to compare both of the array" how are you comparing? "if the dayOfWeek is not present into the officeHoursList" Are you looking for the current day of the week from the officeHoursList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `reduce()` and `filter()` methods

```js
let dayOfWeek = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

let officeHoursList = [{dayOfWeek: "Wednesday", beginHour: "08:30 AM", endHour: "04:30 PM"}]

let result = dayOfWeek.reduce((acc, day) => {

  let officeHour = officeHoursList.filter(officeHour => officeHour.dayOfWeek === day)
  
  if (officeHour.length) {
    acc.push(officeHour)
  } else {
    acc.push({dayOfWeek: day, beginHour: "00:00 AM", endHour: "00:00 PM"})
  }
  
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cycle on the day array and check if the current day is not already present, then add it to the office array

```
dayOfWeek.forEach(function(d){
    if(!officeHoursList.some(function(o){return o.dayOfWeek === d;}){
        officeHoursList.push({
                      dayOfWeek: d, 
                      beginHour: "00:00 AM", 
                      endHour: "00:00 PM"});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This example does not do sorting in desired order which I would leave it upto you (OP) to figure it out.

```js
let dayOfWeek = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
let officeHoursList = [{
  dayOfWeek: "Wednesday",
  beginHour: "08:30 AM",
  endHour: "04:30 PM"
}];

dayOfWeek.map(day => {
  if (!officeHoursList.find(officeHour => officeHour.dayOfWeek === day)) {
    officeHoursList.push({
      dayOfWeek: day,
      beginHour: "00:00 AM",
      endHour: "00:00 PM"
    });
  }
});

console.log(officeHoursList)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,But I want the dayOfWeek,In this case Wednesday should be added on 3rd index.

Comment: @Pintu that's what I have in my statement above as you need to resolve sorting on your own

Answer (score 0):

Ordered list of days and times. If this helps you mark it as accepted answer.

```
function displayDaysInOfficeHours() {
  console.log(
    officeHoursList.map(
      function(officeHour){
        return officeHour.dayOfWeek+','+officeHour.beginHour+','+officeHour.endHour
      }
    )
  );
}

function addNewDaysOfWeek() {
  displayDaysInOfficeHours(); // Show what we start with

  const orderedOfficeHours = [];

  dayOfWeek.forEach(function(dayOfWeek){ // e.g. 'Monday'
    //Q. Is Monday in the list?
    //If I find it I'll keep track of start and end time
    let startAndEndTime = ['00:00 AM','00:00 PM'];
    for(let i=0; i<officeHoursList.length; i++){
      if (officeHoursList[i].dayOfWeek===dayOfWeek) {
        startAndEndTime= [officeHoursList[i].beginHour,officeHoursList[i].endHour];
        break; // Leave loop early if day found
      }
    }

    orderedOfficeHours.push(
      {
        dayOfWeek: dayOfWeek,
        beginHour: startAndEndTime[0],
        endHour: startAndEndTime[1]
      }
    )
  });

  officeHoursList = orderedOfficeHours;

  displayDaysInOfficeHours(); // Shows ordered officeHours
}
```